# Label text overlapped when use plot() to draw NMDS plot

Tags: r, plot, overlap

I try to use plot() to draw NMDS plot with vectors. While the label text showed overlapping. Anyone can help to figure it out please? Thank you!

Here is the plot I got
[image: NMDS plot]

And here is the code I am using

```
dat1=read.csv("nmdsRefinedMetaTable.csv", row.names=1) 
soiltype= dat1[,1]
dat1=dat1[,-1]
head(dat1)
soiltype
dat1$Farm <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat1$Farm))
dat1$Textural.Class <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat1$Textural.Class))
library(ecodist)
dm=distance(scale(dat1), "euclidean") 
nmds_out=nmds(dm, mindim=2, maxdim=2) 
scores=nmds.min(nmds_out)
nmds_out$stress 
mygroups = sort(unique(soiltype)); mygroups 
mycol = c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9" ) 
plot(scores, pch=19, col=mycol[as.factor(soiltype)])
vectors = vf(scores, dat1, nperm=10) 
plot(vectors, col="red", = 1,vjust=1,hjust=1)
library(vegan)
ordiellipse(scores, soiltype, conf=0.6, col=mycol, show.groups=mygroups)
```

Comment: I think in cases of overlapping text you want to use ggrepel

Comment: are you okay with using ggplot()?

Comment: Yeah I think ggplot is a good way. But I don't know how to transfer plot() to ggplot() @Mark